# What is the difference between "activate" and "launch"?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

Here is an example of Applescript code:

```
do shell script "osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\" to activate'"

do shell script "osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\" to launch'"
```

Is there any difference in the behavior of these two commands?

Because, to my eyes, it appears that they accomplish exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Commands Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html) section of the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/index.html):

> [`activate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW60) Brings an application to the front, launching it if
>   necessary.
>
> [`launch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW51) Launches an application, if it is not already running, but
>   does not send it a [run](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW57) command.
>
> If an application is already running, sending it a launch command has
>   no effect. That allows you to open an application without performing
>   its usual startup procedures, such as opening a new window or, in the
>   case of a script application, running its script. For example, you can
>   use the launch command when you don’t want an application to open and
>   close visibly. This is less useful in AppleScript 2.0, which launches
>   applications as hidden by default (even with the run command).