# How to launch mac app via iOS Shortcuts app?

Tags: shortcuts-app

I'm trying to create an iOS shortcut that either launches an app on my mac.  Seems like it should be fairly simple but I can't figure out how to do it.  Lots of mentions I've found in my googling but no simple concise instructions.  My remote machine is set to allow remote management, and I've toyed with the SSH running from the iOS shortcuts app, but I can't figure out what's actually going on and how to designate what app to launch.

How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With SSH access enabled, named Remote Login in the Sharing settings of System Settings on your Mac, note the SSH details behind the ⓘ button.

   [image: Remote Login: On. To log in to this computer remotely, type…]
2. In a shortcut, add the ‘Run script over SSH’ action.

   - Set the script to

     ```
     open -a "app name"
     ```

     See [How can I open an app using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/355037/37797) for details on this command.

     Make sure to use "straight quotes", not “smart quotes”.
   - Set the Host to the IP after the @.
   - Set the User to the username before the @.
   - Provide your Mac account password.

   [image: Run script over SSH action]
3. Run the shortcut.

   The first time, you will be prompted to allow the shortcut to access SSH, and then confirm the fingerprint of the device you're connecting to. You won't be asked these next time.

Comment: Aha, I was very close... thanks!  I will give this a try and accept if (when!) it works =)

Comment: PERFECT, working like a charm.  THANK YOU!!!