# Acrobat Pro DC opens in the background when launching from the CLI

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, iterm, adobe

When I launch Acrobat from iTerm2 / Bash, Acrobat runs and loads the file, but it doesn't load on top of other applications like I would expect.  I have to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (to select the last application) to bring the window to the foreground.  **Is there a way to launch Acrobat such that the window will be on top and take focus?**

*Launch Command*:

```
/Applications/Adobe\ Acrobat\ DC/Adobe\ Acrobat.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeAcrobat file.pdf
```

*Hardware*: Apple M1 Max 
*OS*: MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 
*Acrobat*: Adobe Acrobat Pro Continuous Release 2023.0001.20093

NOTE: Using `open` is not an option because I want to keep `.pdf` files associated with Preview since it's so much faster to launch.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that you can use the `-a` flag to `open` to utilize an application different from the default and it will open with focus.

BTW, this behavior of opening in the background has nothing to do with Acrobat.  Other programs behave the same way.

Credit to:
https://superuser.com/questions/173136/start-app-from-terminal-with-focus

Comment: This is better, and if you need to you can also [use `osascript` to activate or lunch the app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/271684/5472).